# AND OR Conditions Conditions Evaluation

Tags: php

I am trying to run a piece of code based on if conditional. I don't undertand why one condition returns false and the other returns true, they seem to be checking exactly same thing. If anyone can help and tell why use of "isset" changes the returned value.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['parent_id'])!= '' && '
isset($_SESSION['p_email'])!=   '' &&  
isset($_SESSION['child_id']) ||
isset($_SESSION['agency_id'])!= '' && 
isset($_SESSION['a_email'])!= '' && 
isset($_GET['child_id']) !='' || 
isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])!= '' && 
isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])!= '' && isset($_GET['child_id']) !=='' )
```

The **above** returns true, which is correct value.

```
    if( ($_SESSION['parent_id'])!= '' &&  
($_SESSION['p_email'])!= '' &&   
($_SESSION['child_id']) || 
 ($_SESSION['agency_id'])!= '' &&
  ($_SESSION['a_email'])!= '' &&  
($_GET['child_id']) !='' ||  
($_SESSION['admin_id'])!= '' && 
 ($_SESSION['admin_email'])!= '' &&  
($_GET['child_id']) !=='' )
```

The **above** code returns false, which is wrong returned value.

Comment: This is hard to understand. Add some brackets and check again.

Comment: This is *impossible* to understand. It's just about the least readable code you could possibly write. I'm not surprised you don't understand it yourself. `isset()!=''` is nonsense; you either compare the string to `''` *or* you check `isset`, doing both makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have such a complicated condition, you need to rethink the problem. First i would split up the code to more readable parts. I can only guess what you tried to do, but it seems you want something like that:

```
$caseWithParentId = isset($_SESSION['parent_id']) &&
  isset($_SESSION['p_email']) &&
  isset($_SESSION['child_id']);
$caseWithAgencyId = isset($_SESSION['agency_id']) &&
  isset($_SESSION['a_email']) &&
  isset($_SESSION['child_id']);
$caseWithAdminId = isset($_SESSION['admin_id']) &&
  isset($_SESSION['admin_email']) &&
  isset($_SESSION['child_id']);

if ($caseWithParentId || $caseWithAgencyId || $caseWithAdminId)
{
  //...
}
```

Then i wonder why you end up on the same PHP file, with so many possible combinations, usually you have one target for each situation.

Comment: just for complete : if the condition fails you can dump this value and identify where is your probleme is better to has readable code like posted reply

Comment: You can condense it a lot more with only 1 `isset` call: `$caseWithParentId = isset($_SESSION['parent_id'],$_SESSION['p_email'],$_SESSION['child_id']);`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - Thanks for the tip, never used it that way.